# Carrierwave backgrounder with delayed job No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen when uploading image

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, background, carrierwave, delayed-job

Im running a Rails 4.1.2 app on a Digital Ocean Centos Nginx box.

I'm trying to get carrierwave backgrounder to store the images in the background, however everytime the jobs are executed i get the following error back:

```
--- !ruby/struct:CarrierWave::Workers::StoreAsset
klass: Item
id: '40'
column: :main_image

No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /var/www/marketplace_v2/releases/20150603150220/tmp/uploads/1433571984-17438-0890/ie8-fine.jpg
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave_backgrounder-0.4.1/lib/backgrounder/workers/store_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave_backgrounder-0.4.1/lib/backgrounder/workers/store_asset.rb:16:in `open'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave_backgrounder-0.4.1/lib/backgrounder/workers/store_asset.rb:16:in `perform'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:94:in `block in invoke_job'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:91:in `invoke_job'
(eval):3:in `block in invoke_job_with_newrelic_transaction_trace'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.9.275/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:366:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
(eval):2:in `invoke_job_with_newrelic_transaction_trace'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:204:in `block (2 levels) in run'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `call'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:204:in `block in run'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:203:in `run'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:280:in `block in reserve_and_run_one_job'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:280:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:187:in `block in work_off'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:186:in `times'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:186:in `work_off'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:150:in `block (4 levels) in start'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:149:in `block (3 levels) in start'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:148:in `block (2 levels) in start'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:147:in `loop'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:147:in `block in start'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `call'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ClearLocks>'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `call'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block (2 levels) in add'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `call'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block in add'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:146:in `start'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/command.rb:124:in `run'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/command.rb:112:in `block in run_process'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application.rb:265:in `call'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application.rb:265:in `block in start_proc'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:84:in `call'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:84:in `call_as_daemon'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application.rb:269:in `start_proc'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application.rb:295:in `start'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/controller.rb:69:in `run'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons.rb:193:in `block in run_proc'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:88:in `call'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:88:in `catch_exceptions'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons.rb:192:in `run_proc'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/command.rb:110:in `run_process'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/command.rb:91:in `block in daemonize'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/command.rb:89:in `times'
/var/www/marketplace_v2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/command.rb:89:in `daemonize'
bin/delayed_job:5:in `<main>'
```

The strange thing is, the image that is reported missing in the top line of the error, actually exists. Doesn't seem to be a permissions thing either as i've tried setting it to 777 to experiment.

Without carrierwave backgrounder in the image processing works fine, everything is uploaded and the correct versions are created.

Am i missing something here or misunderstanding the setup?

My current code below:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class ItemImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  # include CarrierWave::ImageOptimizer

  def store_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end


  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [50, 50]
  end

  version :gallery do
    process :resize_to_limit => [300, 300]
  end

  version :large_image do
    process :resize_to_limit => [700, 400]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

carrierwave.rb

```
# config/initializers/carrierwave.rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    # Configuration for Amazon S3 should be made available through an Environment variable.
    # For local installations, export the env variable through the shell OR
    # if using Passenger, set an Apache environment variable.
    #
    # In Heroku, follow http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars
    #
    # $ heroku config:add S3_KEY=your_s3_access_key S3_SECRET=your_s3_secret S3_REGION=eu-west-1 S3_ASSET_URL=http://assets.example.com/ S3_BUCKET_NAME=s3_bucket/folder

    # Configuration for Amazon S3
    :provider              => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    :region                => ENV['AWS_REGION']
  }

  config.enable_processing = false

  # For testing, upload files to local `tmp` folder.
  if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.cucumber?
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = false
    config.root = "#{Rails.root}/tmp"
  elsif Rails.env.development?
    config.storage = :file
  else
    # config.storage = :fog
    config.storage = :file
  end

  # config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"                  # To let CarrierWave work on heroku
  config.fog_directory    = ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
end
```

item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'acts-as-taggable-on'
  acts_as_taggable
  acts_as_taggable_on :location
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :categories
  has_many :extra_item_images

  validates :title, :price, :description, presence: true

  mount_uploader :main_image, ItemImageUploader
  store_in_background :main_image
  # process_in_background :main_image
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :extra_item_images
end
```

I'm totally lost, been keeping me going for days and tried everything i could on google so any help would be really appreciated.

Final bit of info. From gemfile.lock

```
carrierwave (0.10.0)
  activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
  json (>= 1.7)
  mime-types (>= 1.16)
carrierwave-imageoptimizer (1.2.1)
  carrierwave (~> 0.8)
  image_optimizer (~> 1.2)
carrierwave_backgrounder (0.4.1)
  carrierwave (~> 0.5)
```